# how does 'netlogo' 's 'any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1' command work?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to get my turtles to turn away when there is a turtle in the patch ahead of them. I have some code

```
to setup
  
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  ;random-seed 13

 let xcord one-of (list min-pxcor max-pxcor)
  crt 3 [
    setxy xcord min-pycor + (random (max-pycor - min-pycor))
    set size 4
    set color yellow
    pen-down
  ]

  ask turtles [
    (ifelse
      xcor = min-pxcor [facexy max-pxcor ycor]
      [facexy min-pxcor ycor]
     )
    ]

end


to go
  
  tick
  ask turtles [search]
  
end

to search

    ifelse any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1 [
      set pcolor blue
      right 90
    ][right (random 21) - 10]

  ;step forward
  fd 1

end
```

but the problem is that turtles seem to detect a turtle ahead even when there is not? I made it so patches turn blue when there is a turtle ahead. You can see the upper blue square definitely did not have any turtles in the surrounding patches. I must be missing something but idk what. I'm using netlogo 6.3.0

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible reason could be, that the turtle is counting itself. The `patch-ahead` looks for turtles on the patch in the direction of the heading with distance 1. The width (or height) of a patch is 1, but if a turtle is "looking" diagonal across a patch this distance can be greater than 1. `turtles-on patch-ahead 1` would therefore report an agentset that includes the calling turtle itself.
If you want the turtle not to be included in the agentset, you can use the `other` reporter.

```
to search

    ifelse any? other turtles-on patch-ahead 1 [
      set pcolor blue
      right 90
    ][right (random 21) - 10]

  ;step forward
  fd 1

end
```